# Google Research's model Mol_dqn not working on Google Colab. I am getting "No module named tensorflow.contrib" error. What can I do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, reinforcement-learning

On Google Colab I am trying to implement Mol_dqn from the paper [Optimization of Molecules via Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.08678)
. I have used the code from Google Research's Github [here](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/mol_dqn).

The model relies on TensorFlow version 1, which Google Colab no longer supports.

How can I get the model to run? How could I update the code scripts to run on Tensorflow ver 2? Is this the only option?

When I try to execute one of the python scripts, the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'" occurs.

I have tried uninstalling Tensorflow and reinstalling version 1.5, but Google Colab would not allow it.

I tried the command

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```

but Google Colab no longer supports it.

Answer (score 0):

`Tensorflow 1.x` is no longer supported in Google Colab as Colab has updated the python version to `3.8` which supports `Tensorflow >=2.2`. Also `tensorflow.contrib` is deprecated api. You can use [tensorflow slim](https://github.com/google-research/tf-slim) instead. Please check this [Migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) for more detail to migrate TF 1.x code to TF 2.x.